# How can I merge two strings of comma-separated numbers in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

For example, there are three rooms.

```
1|gold_room|1,2,3

2|silver_room|1,2,3

3|brown_room|2,4,6

4|brown_room|3

5|gold_room|4,5,6
```

Then, I'd like to get

```
gold_room|1,2,3,4,5,6

brown_room|2,3,4,6

silver_room|1,2,3
```

How can I achieve this?

I've tried: `select * from room group by name;` And it only prints the first row.  And I know CONCAT() can combine two string values.

Comment: You probably know this, but just in case, I'll say that this is a flawed data model. Storing multiple values in one column is just begging for trouble, and this is just the beginning of it.

Comment: That said, for `brown_room`, that's not a concatenation. You've unpivoted the values, sorted them, and repivoted them. Is that a requirement?

Comment: Ah.. I think it's not concatenation. And Yes, I want sorted array @EricBrandt

Comment: I edited the title of this question to describe the goal more clearly. Instead of "concatenate," I would say "merge."

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple values in a string!  Don't store numbers as strings!  And "two rooms"???

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree.. but I thought it would be faster to implement. The data I have is arrays in a string like the question. And what I need is the other numbers. For example, if the data is '1,3,7'. Then, I need '2,4,5,8,9'. And additionally, there's one more parameter that is night value(the numbers show the order of classes). The night value also contains arrays in a string format like '1' or '3,4'. However, this is different time from the daytime schedule. So, it'd be better to store like '10' or '12,13'. And I have no idea how to parse the data to one rows. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Whenever you find yourself putting comma-separated data into a single column in any RDBMS, you're doing something **very wrong**.

Comment: You will regret using this database design. If you have any hope of a robust solution, fix it now.

Comment: The road to hell is paved with code that was "faster to implement". ;) The extra time you spend correcting the data model now will be a fraction of the time you'll waste trying to work with this model down the road.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I agree with you. But 1. the data is more than 2000 rows. 2. I have just one day. 3. this is not production level 4. I need to parse the data with my hands. 
I think I don't have any choice. And I wish I could make them as you suggest, If there's simple way. I think it can take more than a week if I do it with my hands.

Comment: I created new question related to this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62143110/how-can-i-parse-delimited-list-in-string-to-rows

Answer (score 2):

Please use below query,

```
select col2, GROUP_CONCAT(col3) from data group by col2;
```

Below is the Test case,

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ab35e8d66ffe3ac6436c17faf97ee9af

Answer (score 0):

I'm not making an assumption that the lists don't have elements in common on separate rows.

First create a table of integers.

```
mysql> create table n (n int primary key);
mysql> insert into n values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6);
```

You can join this to your rooms table using the FIND_IN_SET() function. Note that this cannot be optimized. It will execute N full table scans. But it does create an interim set of rows.

```
mysql> select * from n inner join rooms on find_in_set(n.n, rooms.csv) order by rooms.room, n.n;
+---+----+-------------+-------+
| n | id | room        | csv   |
+---+----+-------------+-------+
| 2 |  3 | brown_room  | 2,4,6 |
| 3 |  4 | brown_room  | 3     |
| 4 |  3 | brown_room  | 2,4,6 |
| 6 |  3 | brown_room  | 2,4,6 |
| 1 |  1 | gold_room   | 1,2,3 |
| 2 |  1 | gold_room   | 1,2,3 |
| 3 |  1 | gold_room   | 1,2,3 |
| 4 |  5 | gold_room   | 4,5,6 |
| 5 |  5 | gold_room   | 4,5,6 |
| 6 |  5 | gold_room   | 4,5,6 |
| 1 |  2 | silver_room | 1,2,3 |
| 2 |  2 | silver_room | 1,2,3 |
| 3 |  2 | silver_room | 1,2,3 |
+---+----+-------------+-------+
```

Use GROUP BY to reduce these rows to one row per room. Use GROUP_CONCAT() to put the integers together into a comma-separated list.

```
mysql> select room, group_concat(distinct n.n order by n.n) as csv 
  from n inner join rooms on find_in_set(n.n, rooms.csv) group by rooms.room
+-------------+-------------+
| room        | csv         |
+-------------+-------------+
| brown_room  | 2,3,4,6     |
| gold_room   | 1,2,3,4,5,6 |
| silver_room | 1,2,3       |
+-------------+-------------+
```

I think this is a lot of work, and impossible to optimize. I don't recommend it.

The problem is that you are storing comma-separated lists of numbers, and then you want to query it as if the elements in the list are discrete values. This is a problem for SQL.

It would be much better if you did not store your numbers in a comma-separated list. Store multiple rows per room, with one number per row. You can run a wider variety of queries if you do this, and it will be more flexible.

For example, the query you asked about, to produce a result with numbers in a comma-separated list is more simple, and you don't need the extra `n` table:

```
select room, group_concat(n order by n) as csv from rooms group by room
```

See also my answer to [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)